# How to create dynamic switch in list view

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a list view in flutter app. The page on which I'm using it is getting list of options having switch of enabling and disabling them using api request and giving a JSON response. I have added the switch but when i try to on/off, it on and off all the options simultaneously. Now I'm able to set the value because of the new revised code but still the issue is that if the value is set to true then after clicking the switch it turn false but it will not set to true again.

Code for setting value and onChanged used on the switch.

```
bool _value = false;

  void _onChanged(bool value) {
    print(value);
    setState(() {
      if(value == false) {
        _value = false;
      }
      else {
        _value = true;
      }

    });
  }
```

The body code that I use to build the List View

```
new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
          if(data[index]['status'] == '0') {
              _value = false;
          }
          else {
            _value = true;
          }
          return new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: new Row(
                        children: [
                          new Expanded(
                            child: new Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(
                                  child: new Text(data[index]['property']),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Switch(
                              value: _value,
                              onChanged: (bool value) {
                                _onChanged(value);
                          }),
                        ],
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
```

Comment: You should add some code of what you tried and clearly state the problem

Comment: @Rene I have added the code which revised to get the list of switch in a view.

Answer (score 0):

All toggles are set with _value and you change _value in _onChanged, which means that is the place you toggle all switches. You should probably move all item logic into one widget to better understand the logic.

Comment: Can you help me that how can i do it because i'm new to flutter development.

Answer (score 0):

Create a _getList() function and call the _getList() function in body code:

```
body: ListView( 
    children : [
        Column(
            children: _getList()
        ) 
    ]
),
```

Create a new List in _getList() function and use _activeDatas to show switch value.

```
var _activeDatas=["1","0","1","1"];
List <Widget> _getList(){
    var newListWidgets = List<Widget>();
    for (var activeData in _activeDatas) {
        newListWidgets.add(
        // TODO: Whatever layout you need for each widget.
            child: GestureDetector(
                child:Container(
                    height: 40,
                    child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Switch(
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  if((activeData)=="1"){
                                    activeData="0";
                                  }
                                  else
                                    activeData = "1";
                                  print(activeData);
                                });
                              },
                              value: (activeData)=="1"
                          )
                        ],
                    )
                )
            )  
        ); 
    }
    return newListWidgets;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple,
you can create a list of Switch widgets and use them with index of ListView.buider